# Corona SDK/Lua Cannot use external modules

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have recently started programming in Lua with the Corona SDK to make apps and I cannot get my main.lua to use the functions of my menu.lua. I keep getting errors. Here is my code. Thanks for your time.

```
    --main.lua--
    local menu = require( "menu" )
    menu.backgroundStart()

    --menu.lua--
    local transition = require("transition")

menu = {}
backgroundStart = function (  )
    local background = display.setBackground( 0, 0, 0)
    animationStart();
end

animationStart = function ()

    local pixelRadius = 5
    local xCenter = math.random(0, display.contentWidth)
    local yCenter = math.random(0, display.contentHeight)
    local whiteCircles = display.newCircle( background, xCenter, yCenter, pixelRadius )
    whiteCircles.setBackground(255,255,255);
    transition.fadeIn( whiteCircles, { time = 200, delay = 10 } )
end
return M;
end
```

The error I am getting has this text:
error loading module 'menu' from file 'menu.lua':
menu.lua:24 '' expected near 'end'
stack traceback:
C: in function 'require'
?: in function 'require'
main.lua:6 in main chunk
Do you want to relaunch the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with Corona or the use of external modules. As the error message says (`error loading module 'menu' from file 'menu.lua': menu.lua:24 '' expected near 'end'`), the problem is on line 24 in `menu.lua`, which means that the file was loaded correctly. My guess is that you have one more `end` statement than needed on line 24, which would produce `'<eof>' expected near 'end'` message (and `<eof>` got dropped somewhere).

Fix that (and any other) issue and your module should load fine.

Comment: @AlphaBeta, you may accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to require transition, it's included. Any way you have to add your functions to your table that you're returning:

```
menu = {}
menu.backgroundStart = function (  )
```

The last line of menu.lua should be

```
return menu
```

Then when you require the module, the code executes and the menu table gets returned and in main.lua you now have access to those functions.

You do have an extra end at the end of the menu.lua module that you don't need.